# Is it useful to include .js .css files etc in a performance test?

Tags: performance, load-testing, jmeter

For an Angular based web application:
Is it useful to include the requests to get javascript and css files? Knowing that the files will be stored in the browser cache after the first visit.

I am tempted to only include XHR calls like authenticate, loading and saving data, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the purpose of your tests. Are you looking at a small number of users using the system, perhaps just one user, each from the same computer? Are you looking at many users from many computers using the system? For the former once the cache is loaded few JS and CSS etc files will be requested from the server. For the latter, each simulated user will be visiting from another computer and their cache will be, initially, empty, so all the JS and CSS etc should be requested from the server.

Comment: It's for a test with a lot of different users.
You're right I will include the css en js files.
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that JMeter Load Test needs to look as close to reality as possible.

Particular in your case:

1. Real browsers of real users **download all embedded resources** like images, scripts, styles, etc.
2. Real browsers of real users do it **only once**, on the next request(s) those resources are returned from the browser cache.

To simulate this behavior (and also to let JMeter respect "Cache-Control" and "Expires" headers) just add a [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan - it will be the best option.

Other test elements which can make your test more realistic are:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - to represent browser cookies
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - to send "User-Agent", "Accept-Encoding" and other headers which may have impact
- In addition to all above you need to properly configure your HTTP Request samplers (preferably via [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) so you could have all configuration in one place). See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for exact instructions.

Comment: I am already using the cookie manager, header manager and request defaults :)
Will definitely try the cache manager. thanks!